# Stack overflow. number to big to be stored

Tags: c

I'm having an issue when i have 20 as passlength(rows of strings) and 26 letters in those strings.  right now it prints acaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa for that instance, the 26 letters being the alphabet. the amount of permutations is to big to be stored. the highest permutation he will ask for 1048576 permutation.  i'm wanting to print the nth(strength) permutation.

how do i get around the stack overflow problem of the skips number being to large???  i've tried changing the int to long long. i've used printf to see the number of permutations and i get the same number for long long as i do with int.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ALPHA 28

typedef struct {
    int yourpass;
    char letters[ALPHA];
    int temp;
    int skips;
} password;

//declare functions
void FindVariations(int passlength, int strength, password *combo, int j, int x);
void magical(password *combo, int passlength);

int main() {

    int i, j, d, cases, passlength;
    int strength;
    password* combo;

    combo = malloc(ALPHA*sizeof(password));

    // enter number of passwords to compute
    scanf("%d", &cases);

    for (i=0; i<cases; i++) {

        //enter number of strings/length of password
        scanf(" %d ", &passlength);

        // input the letters for password
        for (j=0; j<passlength; j++) {

        scanf(" %s ", combo[j].letters);

        combo[j].temp = strlen(combo[j].letters);
        }

        scanf("%d", &strength);

        // find the total nnumber of permutations
        magical(combo, passlength);

        // find the permutation to print
        FindVariations( passlength, strength, combo, 1, 0);

        // print the wanted password
        for(d=0; d<passlength; d++) {

            printf("%c", combo[d].letters[combo[d].yourpass]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    free(combo);
    return 0;
}

void magical(password *combo, int passlength) {

    int i;
    int total=0;

    for(i=(passlength-1); i>=0; i--) {

        if(i==(passlength-1)) {
            combo[i].skips=1;
            total=combo[i].temp;

        }
        else {
            combo[i].skips=total;
            total*= combo[i].temp;
        }
    }

}

void FindVariations(int passlength, int strength, password *combo, int j, int x) {

    combo[x].yourpass = 0;

    if(x==passlength){
        return;
    }

    if (x<passlength)  {
        while(j<=strength-combo[x].skips) {
            combo[x].yourpass+=1;
            j+=combo[x].skips;
        }
    }

    FindVariations( passlength, strength, combo, j, x+1);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how do i get around the stack overflow?  26*26*26....etc. is such a big number to store.  because only wanting to print one given permutaion(int strength).

Comment: You need to update your question with information about what it is exactly you are trying to do, what exactly is the problem you are facing, and what you have tried to resolve those problems.

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand what a stack overflow is? In your case it's not a matter of storing a big number. It's a matter of using a truckload of memory by using a huge number of recursive function calls.

Every time you make a function call, the compiler adds space for the parameters and internal variables of the function to the program's stack memory. If you do a lot of function calls inside function calls, this makes the program's stack memory grow beyond its allowed limits, generating a stack overflow error.

In the case of your program, however, once you make the `FindVariations` function call, you don't have a need for the previous values of the variables, so you don't actually need the memory overhead that is caused by a recursive function call. This is called [Tail Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion#Relation_to_while_construct).

The easiest solution to prevent the stack overflowing is to turn your recursive solution into an iterative one.

```
void FindVariations(int passlength, int strength, password *combo, int j, int x) 
{
    for (combo[x].yourpass = 0; x < passlength; x++) 
    {
        while(j <= strength-combo[x].skips) 
        {
            combo[x].yourpass+=1;
            j+=combo[x].skips;
        }
    }
}
```